# tableview reloadData not working after successful login / AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the below code in my ViewController.m to log a user in to my app. However on the following ViewController (AccountViewController), I have a tableView. Upon successful login, I want to reload/populate the data in the tableView, but instead after a successful login, I get an empty table. I've put reloadData in viewWillAppear at the top of MyAccountViewController. See below. Not sure why it's doing this, as when I navigate from AccountViewController to another screen and back, the table is populated. Is my AFNetworking bit causing the table not to populate for some reason?

**ViewController.m**

```
[DIOSUser userLoginWithUsername:_userField.text
                    andPassword:_passField.text
                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
                            // Saving to keychain/NSUserDefaults

                            NSDictionary *diosSession = [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user];

                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:diosSession] forKey:@"diosSession"];

                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                            [[DIOSSession sharedSession] getCSRFTokenWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                NSString *csrfToken = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseObject bytes]];
                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:csrfToken forKey:@"diosToken"];
                                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                // failure handler
                            }];

                            wrongLogin.hidden = YES;
                            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                            MyAccountViewController *yourViewController = (MyAccountViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAccount"];
                            [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

                            [self.activityIndicatorViewOne stopAnimating];
                            self.activityIndicatorViewOne.hidden = YES;


                            NSLog(@"Success!");}

                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { NSLog(@"Fail!"); wrongLogin.hidden = NO; }
 ];
```

**AccountViewController.m**

```
       - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [self.tableView reloadData];

        }
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

           [self.tableView reloadData];

        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(ReloadDataFunction:)
                                                     name:@"refresh"
                                                   object:nil];


        [self.tableView reloadData];

        self.descripData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"logouticon4.png"]
                                    //   initWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(flipView)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
        [flipButton release];


        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];

        refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
        [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
        [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.storageData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        userName.text = [[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"name"];
        //emailAddress.text = [[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"mail"];
        NSLog(@"%@", [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]);



        //  DIOSView *view = [[DIOSView alloc] init];
          NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
          [viewParams setValue:@"storeditems" forKey:@"view_name"];
          [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            self.descripData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
              NSLog(@"%@",self.descripData);



      //      [self.tableView reloadData];
        //  [HUD hide:YES];
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }];



        [DIOSNode nodeIndexWithPage:@"0" fields:@"title" parameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"storage_item", nil] pageSize:@"20" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Nodes retrieved!");
           __block int iCount = 0;

            for (id object in responseObject) {
            //    NSLog(@"adding object!");
                [self.storageData setObject:(NSDictionary *)object forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iCount]];
                iCount++;

                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            //failure
        }];


    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self.storageData count] > 0 && self.descripData.count > 0)
    {
        return [self.descripData count];
    }

    else

        return 0;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)

        {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

   if (self.storageData.count > 0 && self.descripData.count > 0) {

        noitemsView.hidden = YES;

        cell.cellCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row+1];

       NSDictionary *title = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [[cell itemName] setText:[title objectForKey:@"node_title"]];

       NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell itemDescrip] setText:[node objectForKey:@"body"]];

       NSDictionary *value = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [[cell valueLabel] setText:[value objectForKey:@"storeditemvalue"]];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.descripData);

     NSDictionary *quantity = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [[cell quantityLabel] setText:[quantity objectForKey:@"numberofitemstored"]];
      NSLog(@"%@", self.descripData);

            NSString *secondLink = [[self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo"];

            [cell.itemPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];

            NSLog(@"%@",secondLink);


              }

    else {
        noitemsView.hidden = NO;
    }

              return cell;
              }
```

Comment: reloadData in ViewWillAppear won't do anything...it's already loading there. Where is the code that provides the tableView data? How does it know to update? You need some sort of sync to your data store in AccountViewController viewWillAppear.

Comment: @Tim See edited code above. My data is refreshed when a user pulls down on the tableView subview (refreshControl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "refresh" observer, but it calls a function you haven't shown here. You set your data it looks like with this:

```
for (id object in responseObject) {
        //    NSLog(@"adding object!");
            [self.storageData setObject:(NSDictionary *)object forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iCount]];
            iCount++;

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
```

but because that is in viewDidLoad, it is only called once, BEFORE viewWillAppear. You need to fill `self.storageData` and `self.descripData` in a separate function, then call THAT function from viewWillAppear, or using your NSNotificationCenter notification from the previous VC.

Comment: Used NSNotificationCenter to execute the above in viewWillAppear. Works like a charm :) Thank you.